# Test Webservice Callout

Tags: apex, webservices, code-coverage, httpcalloutmock, webservicemock

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  I am not getting back any data from my mock callout.  Below- `jsonStr` is what is returned from the webservice and it is being returned as null.

Apex:

```
public PageReference CallWebService(){
    getAccounts(); //WEBSERVICE
    if(jsonStr != NULL) { //MOCK CALL OUT IS RETURNING NULL
        errorMessage();
        saveDateToString();
        updateCRSObject();
    }
    else {
        genericError = 'There has been an error in your organization. Please contact your system administrator for assistance.';
    }
    return null;
}
```

MockClass:

```
@isTest
public class SingleRequestMockClass implements HttpCalloutMock {
    protected Integer code;
    protected String status;
    protected String bodyAsString;
    protected Blob bodyAsBlob;
    protected Map<String, String> responseHeaders;

    public SingleRequestMockClass(Integer code, String status, String body,
                                     Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {
        this.code = code;
        this.status = status;
        this.bodyAsString = body;
        this.bodyAsBlob = null;
        this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
    }

    public SingleRequestMockClass(Integer code, String status, Blob body,
                                     Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {
        this.code = code;
        this.status = status;
        this.bodyAsBlob = body;
        this.bodyAsString = null;
        this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;
    }

    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();
        resp.setStatusCode(code);
        resp.setStatus(status);
        if (bodyAsBlob != null) {
            resp.setBodyAsBlob(bodyAsBlob);
        } else {
            resp.setBody(bodyAsString);
        }

        if (responseHeaders != null) {
             for (String key : responseHeaders.keySet()) {
            resp.setHeader(key, responseHeaders.get(key));
             }
        }
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
static testmethod void firstTestAccount(){
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account Olivia');
    insert a;
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity(AccountId = a.Id, Name = 'IDAnalyticsName', CloseDate = Date.today(), StageName = 'Prospecting');
    insert o;
    Contact c = new Contact(FirstName = 'FirstTest', LastName='LastTest', SSN_Encrypted__c ='000000000', HomePhone='7894561333', MobilePhone='9885556666', Email='test@test123.com', AccountId = a.Id);
    insert c;
    FPC_Address__c addr = new FPC_Address__c(Zip_Code__c = '44543',Address_1__c = 'Test Street ', City__c = 'Unity City',State__c = 'CA', Account__c = a.id, Location_Type__c = 'Home Address', Contact__c = c.Id);
    insert addr;
    Credit_Review__c cr = new Credit_Review__c(Account__c = a.Id, Opportunity__c = o.Id, PG1__c = c.Id);
    insert cr;
    Consumer_Risk_Summary__c crs = new Consumer_Risk_Summary__c(Error_Message__c = 'ID Analytics encountered an error while processing the request.', Credit_Review__c = cr.Id, Position__c = '1');
    insert crs;
    crs.Bankcard_Score__c = '123';
    update crs;
    Id guarantorId1 = [SELECT PG1__c FROM Credit_Review__c WHERE Id = :cr.Id].PG1__c;
    system.assertNotEquals(null, guarantorId1);
    List<Contact> serializedData = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Birthdate, SSN_Encrypted__c, SSN__c, HomePhone, MobilePhone, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = :guarantorId1];
    List<Consumer_Risk_Summary__c> consumerRiskID = [SELECT Id FROM Consumer_Risk_Summary__c WHERE Position__c = '1' AND Id = :crs.Id];
    List<FPC_Address__c> homeAddress1 = [SELECT Address_1__c, City__c, State__c, Zip_Code__c FROM FPC_Address__c WHERE Location_Type__c = 'Home Address' AND Contact__r.Id = :guarantorId1 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
    IDAnalyticsEndPoint__c IDA = new IDAnalyticsEndPoint__c();
    insert IDA;
    IDA.IDAnalyticsEndpointUrl__c = 'https://test.com/I removed this for privacy';
    IDA.GetToken__c = 'https://test.com/I removed this for privacy';
    IDA.APIKEY__c = '114DEF80-1C9E-4563-8352-29819E1E415B';
    update IDA;
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', cr.Id);
    IDAnalyticsController ctrl = new IDAnalyticsController();
    String responseObj = '{"USAddress":{"State":"CA","PostalCode":"44543","Line1":"Test Street","City":"Unity City"},"SocialSecurityNumber":"000000000","ReportAttachmentParentId":"a4uc0000000TiwiAAC","MobilePhone":"9885556666","LastName":"LastTest","HomePhone":"7894561333","GuarantorNumber":"G1","FirstName":"FirstTest","Email":"test@test123.com","DateOfBirth":null,"ContactId":"003c000000mmOGsAAM"}';
    String responseObj2 = '{"USAddress":{"State":,"PostalCode":,"Line1":,"City":"Unity City"},"SocialSecurityNumber":,"ReportAttachmentParentId":"a4uc0000000TiwiAAC","MobilePhone":"9885556666","LastName":"LastTest","HomePhone":"7894561333","GuarantorNumber":"G1","FirstName":"FirstTest","Email":"test@test123.com","DateOfBirth":null,"ContactId":"003c000000mmOGsAAM"}';
    SingleRequestMockClass fakeResponse = new SingleRequestMockClass(200,'Complete',responseObj, null);
    SingleRequestMockClass fakeReturn500 = new SingleRequestMockClass(500,'Error',responseObj2 ,null);
    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, fakeResponse);
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, fakeReturn500);
    ctrl.pullIDAnalyticsReportAPEX();
    ctrl.CallWebService();
    ctrl.removeCR1();
    ctrl.removeCRS1();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

This is the format that I am returned in my actual class:

`USER_DEBUG [240]|DEBUG|this is the NewJSONString1: {"USAddress":{"State":"CA","PostalCode":"00000","Line1":"Test Street","City":"Unity City"},"SocialSecurityNumber":"000000000","ReportAttachmentParentId":"a4uc0000000TiyZAAS","MobilePhone":"9885556666","LastName":"LastTest","HomePhone":"7894561333","GuarantorNumber":"G1","FirstName":"FirstTest","Email":"test@test123.com","DateOfBirth":null,"ContactId":"003c000000mmOSyAAM"}`

Am I putting in the wrong string format for the `responseObj`?

Comment: I am closing this because you essentially need to follow what is in the linked duplicate. Anything beyond that would get into multiple questions. Start with the linked duplicate and get it working without modification. then add to it as needed. You have not posted your class that does the callout so it could be many things including the class that makes the callout not actually doing it and returning null instead of doing the callout

Comment: Once you get the mock response working with a basic class that does a callout start adding it into your tests with the above code. Trace the debug logs or simply look at the coverage data and see where it is breaking. Then post up that question. Generally I think your mock class *may* work but did not test it. I believe your issue may be in the `getAccounts` method

Comment: @Eric, okay thanks for the referenced link. I will break it down more

Comment: Not trying to to be hard handed here so please do not take it that way. Just trying to steer you in the direction to where you can post up a more specific question with appropriate code to allow us to help.